# Computing a KDE and its point-wise error from data with measurement errors

Tags: kernel-smoothing

I have a set of measurements and their associated errors. I would like to compute a kernel density estimate (KDE) and the error of the KDE at each point. The KDE and the KDE error should take into account the measurement errors.

I wondered whether computing confidence bands would be the way to go. However, it does not take into account measurement uncertainties.

Is there a good strategy on how to proceed?